# GSON: modify child JSONs based on values from parent JSON

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, gson

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "baseStrings": [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3"
  ],
  "object" : {
    "name" : "example",
    "string" : "test4",
    "object2" : {
      "name" : "example",
      "object3" : {
        "name" : "example",
        "string" : "test5"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see there is a list of strings in root and also there are some objects which may or may not contains a field called "string". For example "object" and "object3" has it but "object2" hasn't.

What Im looking for is that I want to create and add a field called "strings" in each child which is a list that contains "string" field of their parents and itself plus "baseStrings". For example in this scenario it will be like:

```
{
  "baseStrings": [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3"
  ],
  "object": {
    "name": "example",
    "strings": [
      "test1",
      "test2",
      "test3",
      "test4"
    ],
    "object2": {
      "name": "example",
      "object3": {
        "name": "example",
        "strings": [
          "test1",
          "test2",
          "test3",
          "test4",
          "test5"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea how I can achieve this with help of GSON only? For more information I'm doing this in Kotlin and Android.

Comment: You can create a POJO of above json and convert in to json using Gson.

Comment: I want to do this before deserialization, something like TypeAdapter @AnasMehar